# Как записать тип функции с переменным количеством аргументов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, есть функция, которую нужно сохранить в переменной:

```
def foo(*args: int) -> None:
    pass

# stored_function: ? = foo
```

Как правильно записать тип переменной?

---

Вариант ниже выдаёт `TypeError` во время исполнения:

```
stored_function: Callable[[*int], None] = foo
```

PyCharm (2018.3.4 CE) выводит следующий тип для этой функции:

```
(args: Tuple[int, ...]) -> None
```

Его можно транслировать в

```
Callable[[Tuple[int, ...]], None]
```

Но выяснилось, что это не является официальным стилем и подобный тип не пройдёт проверку даже в самом PyCharm:

```
def boo(func: Callable[[Tuple[int, ...]], None]) -> None:
    func(1, 2, 3)
#           ^  ^ Unexpected argument
```

При этом вызов `boo(foo)` предупреждение не генерирует.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь важно понимать цель добавления аннотации типа.

Если это просто подсказка читающему программисту, то можно использовать любой стиль, принятый в команде. Аннотации в таком случае достаточно исполняться без ошибок (а если добавить строку `from __future__ import annotations`, то подойдёт любая синтаксически верная конструкция).

Если же хочется иметь работающую статическую проверку типов, то здесь ситуация более сложная.

Официальной поддержки таких случаев нет.
[PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable):

> Since using callbacks with keyword arguments is not perceived as a common use case, there is currently no support for specifying keyword arguments with `Callable`. Similarly, there is no support for specifying callback signatures with a variable number of argument of a specific type.

Свободный перевод:

> Так как использование функторов с именованными аргументами не видится частым случаем, в текущем виде нет поддержки определения именованных аргументов для `Callable`. Аналогично нет поддержки указания сигнатуры функторов с переменным количеством аргументов определённого типа.

[PEP-483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks):

> `Callable[[t1, t2, ..., tn], tr]`. [...] There is no way to indicate optional or keyword arguments, nor varargs, [...].

Примерный перевод:

> `Callable[[t1, t2, ..., tn], tr]`. [...] Нет способа обозначить необязательные или именованные аргументы, а также переменное количество аргументов, [...].

В документации к модулю `typing` [предлагается](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) использовать следующий тип:

```
stored_function: Callable[..., None] = foo
```

В таком случае допускаются произвольные аргументы, но на возвращаемое значение всё равно накладывается ограничение.

---

Если есть возможность использовать сторонние инструменты, то mypy содержит экспериментальную возможность обработки такого случая (а также [более сложных вариантов](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html?highlight=varargs#extended-callable-types)):

```
from typing import Callable
from mypy_extensions import VarArg

# def foo...

stored_function: Callable[[VarArg(int)], None] = foo
```